# CORS with vue.js and laravel won't come to work

Tags: laravel, cors, mamp, codekit

I hope you may help a laravel and vue.js newby. I am writing a little application where I need to call the weather api by darksky.net.

Via php it works well. Now I want it more dynamically with vue.js. But if I make an api call via axios, I get the following message:

> Failed to load > https://api.darksky.net/forecast/myDarkSkyKey/37.8267,-122.4233: Response > to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-> Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin > 'http://localhost:5757' is therefore not allowed access.

I red a lot stuff about cors and tried to include the headers with middleware as explained [here](https://blog.nikhilben.com/2015/09/02/laravel5-rest-api-and-cors/), and I even tried the ["laravel-cors" package by berryvhd](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors), but I am running against that "No 'Access-Control-> Allow-Origin' header is present" wall again and again.

Do you have any advises or a clue what I am doing wrong? I tried that much, even including these

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

directly into public/index.php

I know its not the fine way, but I wanted to figure out whats working. But nothing helps.

I am working with the latest laravel master and vue.js 2, MAMP and CodeKit.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to control darksky's headers. Making that call on client side would expose your API key anyway. You might want to proxy it through your PHP backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your thoughts!
I found a solution working for me: proxy servers i.e. https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

so I can do my request to darksky as follows:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/myDarkSkyKey/37.8267,-122.4233

That will work for me. Only one bad taste -> what if the herokuapp server is down!?

Comment: CORS is there to protect users so you might want to reconsider this strategy.

Comment: Hey apokryfos, but how? I cannot control the darksky-headers. So how can I config the laravel framework to accept the darksky-headers? Nothing I red in the past was helping me.

Comment: Set up a proxy route on your own server which you can control. Users trust you and you in turn trust the cors-anywhere app which currently is fine but its not under your control so you don't know what will happen if it falls under malicious control.